# Trouble saving an xml file using DOMDocument->save('filename')

Tags: php

I have a short PHP program that loads an XML file (test02.xml) and then attempts to save it in another file.

The program is:

```
<?php
//The next three lines are needed to open a file for writing on the server I use.

$stream_options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => TRUE));
$stream_context = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$fxml = fopen("ftp://userid:password@www.yurowdesigns.com/public_html/programs/test03.xml","w",0,$stream_context);

//The next three lines create a new DOMDocument, load the input file, "test02.xml"  
//and attempt to save the loaded file in the output file "test03.xml"

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load("test02.xml");
$doc->save("test03.xml");
?>
```

The file test03.xml opens properly and is created if it does not exist. However, there is no output in it. The loaded file, test02.xml, is non-empty and well formed XML. I have loaded and read it successfully with other PHP programs.

When I run the above program, I get the message:

Warning: DOMDocument::save(test03.xml) [domdocument.save]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/yurow/wwwroot/yurowdesigns.com/programs/xmlTest.php on line 8.

I have checked the syntax of the 'save' command at:

phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.dom-domdocument-save.php

and it appears to be correct. Any idea what is causing this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user trying to create the file is not "yurow" (a user who likely has permission to create the file). Rather it's a user such as "apache" or "httpd". Often, systems are set up to disallow the apache/httpd user from creating files inside the web root. This is done for security purposes and I would not recommend trying to circumvent it by giving apache/httpd write access to your webroot. Instead, you could create the document somewhere inside /home/yurow (just not inside /home/yurow/wwwroot). An example might be: /home/yurow/xmldata/test02.xml. You may need to adjust permissions on this directory to allow the apache/httpd user to write to it.

Comment: @user1107199 It sounds like /home/yurow is your "/" root level when viewing with ftp. So, you could simply create the xmldata directory next to your wwwroot directory. In other words, viewing / in your ftp client, you'd see /wwwroot and /xmldata (along with whatever else you have in there)

Comment: I created the folder /XMLFiles and successfully created the file test03.xml with the fopen() statement below: 
$fxml = fopen("ftp://userid:password!@www.yurowdesigns.com/XMLFiles/test03.xml","w",0,$stream_context);
(line 10) $doc->save("/home/yurow/XMLFiles/test03.xml");
However,the save() command above continues to produce the warning message: Warning: DOMDocument::save(/home/yurow/XMLFiles/test03.xml) [domdocument.save]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/yurow/wwwroot/yurowdesigns.com/programs/xmlTest.php on line 10.  It looks like this baby is locked down tight!!

Comment: @user1107199 I don't understand why you'd create the file through ftp and then read it locally. Assuming you've got a reason to do this, you might try adding a umask call to the top of your script. e.g. umask(0000). And/or make sure the the XMLFiles directory is set so that you and the apache user can read/write to it.

Comment: I did not try your last suggestion @RobApodaca.  Instead I wrote my web site hosting service to see what they suggested.  I received an e-mail telling me that they were in the process of upgrading their operating system and that the problem would be fixed in the next week or so.  My website and all associated files were ported over to the new system and everything seems to be working fine now.  Thanks again for your time and helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Permission denied means your script cannot write data into the xml file because the file does not have the correct permission to write data into it. Try the following:

1. Create empty xml file (test03.xml).
2. Change the xml file permissions to 775 or 777 depending on your server.
3. Save the xml data into your new file.

Hope this helps

Comment: Normally a good idea.  I have been able to do that with other web hosting services, but do not have access to permissions on this one.